# Scala List object methods implementation

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-collections

I need to implement my own List class in Scala. I've implemented:

```
trait List[+A] {
  /** The first element */
  def head: A
  /** The rest of the elements */
  def tail: List[A]

  def map[B](f: A => B): List[B]
  def flatMap[B](f: A => List[B]): List[B]
  def filter(f: A => Boolean): List[A]

  // Concatenate two lists
  def concat[B >: A](that: List[B]): List[B] = this match {
    case Empty => that
    case NonEmpty(head, tail) => NonEmpty(head, tail concat that)
  }
}

/** The empty list, also known as Nil */
case object Empty extends List[Nothing] {
  def head = throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Empty.head")
  def tail = throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Empty.tail")

  def map[B](f: Nothing => B): List[B] = Empty
  def flatMap[B](f: Nothing => List[B]): List[B] = Empty
  def filter(f: Nothing => Boolean): List[Nothing] = Empty

  override def toString = "Empty"
}
```

And now I need to implement filter, flatMap and Map methods:

```
case class NonEmpty[A](head: A, tail: List[A]) extends List[A] {


    //def map[B](f: A => B): List[B] = ???
      //def flatMap[B](f: A => List[B]): List[B] = ???
      def filter(predicate: A => Boolean): List[A] = {        
      }
```

For instance method `filter(predicate: A => Boolean): List[A]` how can I iterate through every element in this list? How can I check if given predicate is true or false? (tried `if(predicate(head))` - doesn't work for some reason.)
Thank you for help.

Comment: It looks like an homework, maybe you could tell us what you've tried and whre your stuck more precisely.

Comment: Also, do you need a tail recursive version or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to traverse the elements with `head` and `tail`:

```
def filter(f: A => Boolean): List[A] = {
  def loop(xs: List[A], ys: List[A]): List[A] =
    if (xs == Empty) ys else loop(xs.tail, if (f(xs.head)) NonEmpty(xs.head, ys) else ys)
  loop(this, Empty).reverse
}
```

This implementation can be defined in `List`. The last thing you need for this is the `reverse` method. You can implement it the same way as `filter` - use an inner method to traverse all elements.

Instead of `reverse` you can use a non-tail-recursive implementation, which must not reversed and can be implemented in the subclasses:

```
def filter(f: A => Boolean): List[A] =
  if (f(head)) NonEmpty(head, tail filter f)
  else tail filter f
```

The other methods can be defined in a similar way.

Comment: thanx for your help, I didn't know about NonEmpty(head, tail filter f)

Comment: @RicardoSimmus How do you mean, you "didn't know"?

Answer (score 1):

Often, recursion gets easier when you just *live in Fairyland* and pretend (almost) everything  already works.

Suppose filter already did what you asked, how would you use filter to make it work for yet another element?

Well, you can decide whether you want to to include the first element of your list (depending on `f`), and let filter, "which already works", handle the rest. Then just concatenate the list.

```
def filter(f: A => Boolean) : List[A] = {
  if (f(head)) NonEmpty(head, tail.filter(f))
  else tail.filter(f)
}
```